# Create form and submit as PDF in dreamweaver

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, dreamweaver

I'm helping my father with some technical stuff for his business and can't seem to find an answer to a seemingly simple task.  He has given me several printed forms that he would like to put on his website for clients to fill out, rather than having them do it physically and scanning the form to a PDF each time.

I have figured out how to create the form in Dreamweaver and submit to an email, but I'm trying to figure out a way to submit the form via email as an attached PDF file that shows the contents of the form exactly as it looks on the website (logos, fields, etc.), while saving it with a unique name (such as last name or date on the form).

I have a little experience with PHP but not enough to figure out how to write a script for this purpose or even where to start on a task like this.  Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: www.tcpdf.org might be of help

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/) as a PHP library to do this. Refer to [This guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.installation.php) to install it. All of the functions I will mention are from php.net

First, you'll need to call [PDF_begin_document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-begin-document.php) to begin the document under a specified filename. You may then use [PDF_setfont()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-setfont.php) to set the font to use(Refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-setfont.php#10254 for the core fonts you don't need to embed, it looks as if they may not support size>12)

Create a page with  [PDF_begin_page_ext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-begin-page-ext.php)

You can then use [PDF_add_textflow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-add-textflow.php) to add text from strings(Use string manipulation as it is easier then groping 5-subroutine-deep with textflows, I think \n is supported)

End the page after adding your textflows with [PDF_end_page_ext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-end-page-ext.php)

Be sure to use [PDF_end_document()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-end-document.php) to end the document. When you began the document, it took a filename. You will find the PDF there.

Comment: If you are confused or want more advanced options, see http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Working-with-Images-and-Text-Flows-in-PDF-Files-with-PHP-5/3/. I am only giving a basic method for the minimum needed.